# Getting Information by 'STS ' Consider using bean inheritance to simplify configuration of the X bean

Tags: spring, spring-boot, autowired

I am using Spring Boot with Spring Data. Spring Boot class looks like

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages={"sm.business","sm.repository"})
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = { DataBaseConfig.class,ApplicationContextProvider.class,SteermeetRepositoryLocator.class })
public class App {
  public static void main(String args[]) {
    SpringApplication.run(App.class, args);
  }
}
```

Additional Warning: It may be possible to use a parent bean to share configuration with the the following beans: A, B, C? What needs to be done for **proper** bean mapping or autowiring Spring Data repositories? Note: Autowiring is working fine. My Beans map:

[image: Bean Map]